# How to implement double bold bar header with multiple lines?

Tags: header-footer

[image: header]

I'm very new to `LaTex` and I want to implement the structure above by myself.
What I only know right now is the `fancyhdr` package but seemed like it didn't work.

I'm really new to `LaTex` and now I have no idea where to start, what to learn, such that I can implement this structure.

Would you give me some hints?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a minimal example of what you tried so far?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, can you show, what you try so far. `fancyhdr` with combination with some other package seems to be right toll for what you like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fancyhdr` package allows you to put a table in the header. By using `tabularx` you can ensure the table spans the entire `\linewidth`, and you can make the rules thicker by changing `\arrayrulewidth`. Doing this inside `\fancyhead` should limit this change to the header, thus not affecting other tables in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headheight=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhead[L]{%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.3em}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{2.5cm}Xl}
\hline
CS 70 & Discrete Mathematics and Probability Theory & \\
Spring 2019 & Satish Rao and Babak Ayazifar & {\large HW 0}\\
\hline\\[-2ex]
 & \centering{\small Due: Friday 1/25, 10 PM} &
\end{tabularx}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]